# How to get database value on label in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am beginner level programmer. Actually i have used two combo box named as "Category" and "Location". When i will click on submit then it should display the category of chemicals and location respectively from database on the labels itself.

Comment: what have you done so far ......please provide code ....

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this?

```
 Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    connetionString = "ConnetionString;"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select column1, column2, column3, column4 from Table1 where Id='" & TextBox9.Text & "'", connection)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        connection.Close()

        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            label1.Text = "blablabla" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("column1").ToString()
            label2.Text = "blablabla" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("column2").ToString()
            label3.Text = "blablabla" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("column3").ToString()
            label4.Text = "blablabla" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("column4").ToString()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Form4.TextBox1.Text = "Failed to connect to database"
        Form4.Show()

    End Try
    Return False
```